# Is Adcolony support windows universal

Tags: windows, adcolony

Currently I'm using a Unity plugin for `Adcolony`. There are 3 platforms that `Adcolony` supports: `iOS`, `Android`, `Amazon`.

My question is: does `Adcolony` currently support Windows universal and can I share my apps with `Adcolony` ads on Windows store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is No. We don't support Ads on Windows OS.

Comment: so, you don't support but if the ads show on windows OS with Unity plugin can i continue my monetize?